# SUMIF and VLOOKUP combination

Tags: excel

I have this worksheet with Sales data by customer (customer can repeat many times in the column) and by month (columns). How can I sumif by customer for specified month? I want to have the month as a variable.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$15 = B19)*($B$1:$M$1 = B20),$B$2:$M$15)
```

Or you can use this SUMIF() with INDEX/MATCH:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,B19,INDEX(A:M,0,MATCH(B20,1:1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. It didn't work at first because I had a bunch of N/As in the column A which is actually a formula and as soon I removed them, it worked!!! Bingo!

Comment: @OS71 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It will remove the question from the unanswered queue.